# Change the "value" attribute of the selected option in "Select" control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve the following result:

There is a `<select>` control. Below that is a `textbox`. I want to assign the value entered in this textbox to the `value` attribute of a particular `option` in the `<select>` control.

For example:-
Say, following is the `<select>` dropdown:-

```
<select id="anyid">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="custom">Custom</option>
</select>
```

Say `4` is entered in the `textbox`, then `onkeyup` of the textbox, I want the `value` attribute of the `Custom` option to be `4`.
So after this the `<select>` options would be:-

```
<select id="anyid">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">Custom</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas? I would prefer jQuery over Javascript.

Comment: and if the value entered in textbox isn't valid for select? Sounds like a strange UI to me

Comment: This seems quite backward? Why wouldn't you allow the user to use the select box?

Comment: @charlietfl You are right but this was the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a class/id assigned to your `custom` option.

`<option class="customOption" value="custom">Custom</option>`

Then you can do:

```
$('#myTextBox').on('keyup', function () {
    $('.customOption').val(this.value);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bbaY2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("textbox").keyup(function(){
         var newValue =        $(this).val();
         $("option").each(function(){
             if($(this).html() == "Custom")
             {
                $(this).val(newValue);
             }    
         });

    });
});
```

Please try above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="anyid">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="custom">Custom</option>
</select>
<input type="text" onkeyup="fillCustomValue(this)"/>
<script>
    function fillCustomValue(elem) {
        document.getElementById('anyid').options[document.getElementById('anyid').options.length - 1].value = elem.value;
        document.getElementById('anyid').options[document.getElementById('anyid').options.length - 1].innerHTML = elem.value;
    }
</script>
```

**Try this without jQuery**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#va').keyup(function(){
    $('#anyid option[value=custom]').attr('value',$(this).val()) 
});
```

OR

```
$('#va').keyup(function(){
        $('#customIDofUrOption').attr('value',$(this).val()) 
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xA8kG/)

Comment: Wouldn't this stop working when the second `keyup` event is fired?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $('#id').val() to set value for option.

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $("#myInput").keyup(function () {
        $('#custom').val($("#myInput").val());
        alert($('#custom').val());
    });
}
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xuqKP/)